# 404 using Angular2, angular2-websocket and typings

Tags: websocket, angular, systemjs

```
...
import {$WebSocket} from "angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket";

@Injectable()
export class DeviceService {

    private logger:Logger;
    private ws:$WebSocket;

    constructor(
        private _logger: Logger
    ) {
        this.logger=_logger;
        this.ws = new $WebSocket("ws://nodered-iot.net/ws/devices");
    }

    private _devices:Device[] = [];

    getDevices() {

        this.ws.send("Hello");
   ...
```

On my browser I get this :

GET http://localhost:1880/node_modules/angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket 404 (Not Found)I 
@ system.src.js:4597(anonymous function) 
http://localhost:1880/node_modules/angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket(…)

I use this definition on index.html

```
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
    System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}},
        map: {
            'angular2-websocket': 'node_modules/angular2-websocket'
        }
    });
    System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

****** EDIT *******

i successfully found the FIX as it :

System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
            packages: {
                'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'},
                'js': { defaultExtension: 'ts' }},
            map: {
                'angular2-websocket': 'js'
            }
        });
        System.import('app/main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));

I had to copy files from node_module into a new js folder. This is not very nice but I don't know how to make this available on client side if these files are not on the 'public' folder of nodeJs :/

Comment: How have you included the module and referenced it? Are you using SystemJS?

Comment: Yes, I am using SystemJS

Comment: Also If i add this to my index.html :         <script src="js/angular2-websocket.js"></script>        then I got this error : Uncaught TypeError: Unexpected anonymous System.register call

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's a SystemJS configuration. You try this:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
      'angular2-websocket': 'node_modules/angular2-websocket'
    },
    packages: {
      (...)
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work. What do I need to add something on 'packages' too ?

Comment: I will try to come back on it doing new tests asap. I don't have a lot of free time for my POC and it is quite complex mixing a lot of stuff ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Anoher solution is to change the Root of NodeRed as it instead pointing to 'public' folder :

```
// Serve up the welcome page
httpStatic: path.join(__dirname,"/"),
```

then we can declare on the index.html :

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket.js"></script>
```